# The computer does not [receives/receive] its updates

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, grammaticality

Should I use `s` in receive when I use `does` before it?

> the computer does not receives/receive its updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

When you use "does", "did" then verb is not to be changed to past or past participle.

> The computer does not receive its updates